# How to underline a label text in ext js?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I am creating a label with a text in EXTJS. What config should should I specify to show it underlined?

```
{
    xtype: 'label',
    width: 130,
    text: 'CLIENT NAME'
    // style:'?'
 }
```

I want the label text CLIENT NAME underlined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `text-decoration` style to underline it.

```
{
    xtype: 'label',
    width: 130,
    text: 'CLIENT NAME',
    style: 'text-decoration:underline'
}
```